# Prefer default export eslint error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this eslint error:

> Prefer default export

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Section">HomePage</div>
    );
  }
}

export { HomePage };
```

**I have tried doing:**
`export { default as Homepage };`

and then I get a fatal parsing error.

Then I changed it to:

```
export default HomePage;
```

Which clears the eslint error.

But then throws:

> './HomePage' does not contain an export named 'HomePage'.

Because I am calling HomePage like this:
`import { HomePage } from './HomePage';`

If I remove the brackets then I get this error:

> "export 'default' (imported as 'HomePage') was not found in
>   './HomePage'

```
import HomePage from './HomePage';
<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
```

What would be the proper way of changing this to the preferred default export?

Comment: Have you tried something like `<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component=(props) => < HomePage {...props} />` offcourse after using `export default HomePage;` and then importing `import  HomePage  from './HomePage';`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From [`eslint-plugin-import`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-default-export.md)

> **When there is only a single export from a module, prefer using default export over named export.**

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  //....
}

export default HomePage
```

In another file :

```
import HomePage from './Hello';
```

Check here [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/9y0w3knm8w)

Comment: what is the issue with this `<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using functions:

```
function HomePage() {
    function aHelperMethod() {
        //
    }

    return {
        aHelperMethod,
    }
}
```

Now to import it in another file

```
import HomePage from './Hello';
```

And to use it you'll have to instantiate it

```
const homePage = HomePage()
homePage.aHelperFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases there should be more than one named export in the module.

```
export const foo = 'foo';
export const bar = 'bar';
```